# bootstrap 5 tooltip blinks once and goes away

Tags: bootstrap-5

I tried to install the tooltip via code:

```
  $('[data-toggle="title"]').each(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t && $t[0]) {
        new bootstrap.Tooltip($t[0]);
    }
  });
```

It blinks, meaning it shows up and then immidiatelly after 1 second it fades away and never shows again. Why is it happening?

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. Are you using jQuery with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: @Zim no i am using Chibi https://github.com/kylebarrow/chibi but boostrap dropped jquery anyway?

Comment: Yes it's no longer required, but you can still use jQuery with Bootstrap 5. From the code it's hard to tell.

Comment: which bootstrap 5 version are you using? It was bug in bootstrap 5.0 version. Please use latest v5.0.2 and then try.

Answer (score 0):

I add..
if you don't enter "bs" to "data-toggle" (so "data-bs-toggle") that code will never work with bootstrap 5